# How to solve for differentials to find Jacobian in system of equations?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization, matrix-calculus

I was reading the paper [Input Convex Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.07152) and couldnt understand part of the derivation for proposition 3 (Section G in supplementary materials). I have put an image of the section below:

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHYFU.png)

The authors describe using differentials to solve for the desired gradients. In the first part, for equations 35 to 37 they describe a trick of replacing dh for I. However, when getting the Jacobian for G that clearly does not work and it is not mentioned how to extend the trick for it to work in this case. I tried reading on matrix differentials, but could not understand this derivation. Does anyone know how to proceed from equation 38 to 39?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper cleverly defines a vector
$$\eqalign{
c=\begin{bmatrix}c_y\\c_\lambda\\c_t\end{bmatrix} = -M^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial y}\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
}$$
Other than the fact that it's symmetric, the details of the $M$ matrix are not important.

The $\,c\,$ vector is used to simplify calculations, like the following for equation $(37)$
$$\eqalign{
\bigg(\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial y}\bigg)^Tdy
 &= \begin{bmatrix}
\Big(\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial y}\Big)^T
&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}dy\\d\lambda\\dt\end{bmatrix} \cr
 &= -\begin{bmatrix}
\Big(\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial y}\Big)^T
&0&0\end{bmatrix}M^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}0\\dh\\0\end{bmatrix} \cr
 &= c^T\begin{bmatrix}0\\dh\\0\end{bmatrix} 
 = c_\lambda^Tdh = c_\lambda:dh \cr
\bigg(\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial y}\bigg)^T\frac{\partial y}{\partial h}
 &= c_\lambda \cr\cr
}$$
The calculation to obtain equation $(39)$ is similar, using terms involving $dG$ instead of $dh$ 
$$\eqalign{
\bigg(\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial y}\bigg)^Tdy
 &= \begin{bmatrix}
\Big(\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial y}\Big)^T
&0&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}dy\\d\lambda\\dt\end{bmatrix} \cr
 &= -\begin{bmatrix}
\Big(\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial y}\Big)^T
&0&0\end{bmatrix}M^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}dG^T\lambda\\dG\,y\\0\end{bmatrix} \cr
 &= c^T\begin{bmatrix}dG^T\lambda\\dG\,y\\0\end{bmatrix} \cr\cr
 &= c_y^TdG^T\lambda + c_\lambda^TdG\,y \cr
 &= \lambda^TdG\,c_y + c_\lambda^TdG\,y \cr
 &= \Big(\lambda c_y^T + c_\lambda y^T\Big):dG \cr
\bigg(\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial y}\bigg)^T\frac{\partial y}{\partial G}
 &= \lambda c_y^T + c_\lambda y^T \cr\cr
}$$
**NB:**  The authors use a different layout format for gradients, which is why mine are transposed compared to those in the paper.

Also, I've used subscripts for the components of the $c$ vector; using superscripts is just ugly.

Comment: Thanks for the answering! It's very helpful, I can understand the process now. I have one more question if you could help on this one as well. On another paper by same authors, they have similar derivation (see [here](https://i.imgur.com/j2tqIw7.png)). Thanks to your answer I can understand how to derive all gradients, except for the one for Q. I cannot get to their term with 1/2 in front. Do you know where that comes from?

Comment: Forgot to link the other paper if you want: [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00443). Thanks again!

Comment: It doesn't follow from their setup. It looks more like an ad hoc attempt to enforce a symmetry-constraint on the $Q$ term.

Comment: Yeah, by using the same approach you did here I got 
$$
\frac{\partial\ell}{\partial z}dz
 = \begin{bmatrix}d_z\\d_\lambda\\d_\nu\end{bmatrix} ^T\begin{bmatrix}-dQ z\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} 
 = -d_z^T dQ \,z 
\Rightarrow \frac{\partial\ell}{\partial z} \frac{\partial z}{\partial Q}
 = -d_z z^T 
$$
Did I make a mistake somewhere? This doesnt seem to be equal to the one presented on the paper.

Comment: No mistake. It appears that the authors took this result and applied a  symmetry constraint, transforming it into $$-\tfrac{1}{2}(d_zz^T+zd_z^T)$$ for some unspecified reason.